# Restarting javascript setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that gets data from database using `javascript setTimeout` but i need to know how to restart this setTimeot to check database again how do i do this without having to use `setInterval`.

```
var update = 0;
var chatUpdate = setTimeout(function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "get_chat.php",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (response) {
          $(".msgView").html(response);
          if (response !== lastResponse) {
              var audio = new Audio('audio/solemn.mp3')
              audio.play()
          }
          lastResponse = response
      }
  });
}, 2000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: a) why not use `setInterval`? b) just call `setTimeout` again. It helps if you don't use an anonymous function here.

Comment: where do you want to restart that setTimeout??

Comment: Put the code in a named function, then from your success or complete handler add `setTimeout(namedFunction, 2000)`. Note that you can't literally "restart" a previous timeout, you can only call `setTimeout()` again.

Comment: @JVLobo don't understand what you mean by where.. But i want to restart it after 10 seconds i guess.

Comment: @MattBurland you mean `setInterval(function() {setTimeout(function () {...}, 200)}, 10000}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your function to a variable, and call setTimeout on it again.

```
var update = 0;
var chatUpdate = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_chat.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $(".msgView").html(response);
            if (response !== lastResponse) {
                var audio = new Audio('audio/solemn.mp3')
                audio.play()
            }
            lastResponse = response
            setTimeout(chatUpdate, 2000);
        }
    });
};
setTimeout(chatUpdate, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var update = 0;
var chatUpdate = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_chat.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
            $(".msgView").html(response);
            if (response !== lastResponse) {
                var audio = new Audio('audio/solemn.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }
            lastResponse = response;
        }
    });
};
setTimeout(chatUpdate, 2000);
```